# Chrome, WIndows Authentication and XHR

Tags: .net, angularjs, google-chrome, authentication, xmlhttprequest

we are developing app with AngularJS for frontend and C# .NET for Backend rest services.
We use a Windows Authentication for login against domain. We use actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity for retrieve the user sent by the browser.
Works fine except when we do a logout, forcing browser to ask new credentials to user. The user sents back new credentials, and from here, for each XHR request done with AngularJS $http, some requests send new Credentials on actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity but other ones will send the old credentials, seems they are cached somethere on the browser. We tried to refresh the page but the problem stills happens.
We believe that it's happening in Chrome, but not in IE.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

$http has an option cache you can set it to false:

```
$http.get(url, {cache:false})
```

from the documentation:

> Caching $http responses are not cached by default. To enable caching, you must set the config.cache value or the default cache
>   value to TRUE or to a cache object (created with $cacheFactory). If
>   defined, the value of config.cache takes precedence over the default
>   cache value.
>
> In order to:
>
> cache all responses - set the default cache value to TRUE or to a
>   cache object cache a specific response - set config.cache value to
>   TRUE or to a cache object If caching is enabled, but neither the
>   default cache nor config.cache are set to a cache object, then the
>   default $cacheFactory($http) object is used.
>
> The default cache value can be set by updating the
>   $http.defaults.cache property or the $httpProvider.defaults.cache
>   property.
>
> When caching is enabled, $http stores the response from the server
>   using the relevant cache object. The next time the same request is
>   made, the response is returned from the cache without sending a
>   request to the server.
>
> Take note that:
>
> Only GET and JSONP requests are cached. The cache key is the request
>   URL including search parameters; headers are not considered. Cached
>   responses are returned asynchronously, in the same way as responses
>   from the server. If multiple identical requests are made using the
>   same cache, which is not yet populated, one request will be made to
>   the server and remaining requests will return the same response. A
>   cache-control header on the response does not affect if or how
>   responses are cached.

Comment: Seems that is not the problem, as we are not using cache = true. In fact, server recieves the request (so it's not cached), but the problem lies in the request data that sends browser to server. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Then the problem is that the old credentials are not freed , the directive or what ever is in charge of this is never destroyed.. so it remembers the old credentials. can you post some code of how you do this?

Comment: But I'm not destroying the directive and all JS instances with page refresh?